# Oracle, dynamic sql and named parameters

Tags: oracle, dynamic-sql

(I've found this which partly answers the question, the declare way would look neater though given that my sql is will be used in oracle and mssql:)
[Binding variables in dynamic PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606352/binding-variables-in-dynamic-pl-sql)

I have some dynamic sql which I'm executing using syntax like the below:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE plsql_block USING employeeid, sortname;
```

and I can then access those variables inside the dynamic sql using :1, :2, etc.
Can I use named parameters instead? something like

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE plsql_block USING employeeid => employeeid
```

and then access them inside the dynamic sql using :employeeid rather than relying on position?

If not my thought is to do something like this at the beginning of the sql:

```
declare employeeid varchar(15 := :1;
```

and then I can change my dynamic sql to my hearts content without worrying about positioning.

Is there a better way?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your workaround is what I have used in the past.
There's also good old [DBMS_Sql](http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_sql.html), which allows binding variables like you would be able to via OCI. (Which is basically what DBMS_Sql seems to be doing anyways ;-) )

Answer (score 3):

You can use named arguments in `DBMS_SQL`:

```
DECLARE
        res INT;
        cr INT;
BEGIN
        cr := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
        DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cr, :plsql_block, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
        DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE(cr, ':employee', :employee);
        res := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(cr);
        DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cr);
END;
```